# convert from int32 to int

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to compare int32 with int   or convert int32 to int?

Looks like No working this way:
Int = (int) Int32;

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224645/convert-from-int32-to-int/) by [chenchengshao@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/25677/chenchengshao@gmail.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-01-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-01-20**:
This forum is primarily for questions about ROS (Robot Operating System), and your question does not appear to be about ROS. You will probably get a better answer by asking on a general programming site like Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the int32 come from a std::msgs you can access the value with .data

int var = yourMsg.data

here is the documentation : http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Int32.html

---

Originally posted by [F.Brosseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/22477/f.brosseau/) with karma: 379 on 2016-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2